# Extract all nodes with specific Name, but without nested elements

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

How could I extract all the nodes from the current node, but without nested elements?

For example this could be my document:

```
<Document>
    <Members>
        <Member Name="A">
            <Member Name="A"/>
            <Member Name="B"/>
        </Member>
        <Member Name="B"/>
        <Member Name="C">
            <Member Name="A">
                <Member Name="A"/>
            </Member>          
        </Member>
    </Members>
</Document>
```

I could use the following:

```
var nodes = xml.SelectNodes(".//Member");
```

but it results with selecting all the nodes, even nested.

I would like to use it recurrently to extract nested nodes, so I cannot write:

```
var nodes = xml.SelectNodes("Document/Members/Member");
```

So basically, what I would like to receive is:

- when I call it on members,  it returns members A,B,C
- when I call it on member A, it returns nested members A,B
- when I call it on member C, it returns nested member A

Comment: You say: `when I call it on member C, it returns nested member A`; Which nested member A , should you get?  the direct `child` OR it's `grandchild`

Answer (score 1):

XPath 3.1 has an `innermost` function so I think you want e.g. `innermost(expression//Member)`. XPath 3.1 is supported for .NET/C# using Saxon-HE .NET.

With XPath 1.0 as supported by Microsoft I think e.g. `expression//MEMBER[not(node())]` will give the leaf `MEMBER` elements.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an XQuery predicate filter to get only the `Member` nodes with the right `@Name` attribute, then go down to all *its* `Member` nodes.

```cs
var someName = "A";

var nodes = xml.SelectNodes($@"//Member[@Name=""{someName}""]/Member");
```

For the first requirement, you would just do

```cs
var nodes = xml.SelectNodes($@"//Members/Member");
```

ideally you should use the newer `XDocument` and `XNode` classes, as they are faster and easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

The double slash indicates the descendant path, whereas it sounds like you want the child path. This is `./Member` or more simply `Member`.

Bear in mind though that the child elements your get back still have their descendant elements within them (i.e. you've only selected the children, but the children contain their descendants).

**EDIT**

From your comment, I'm not sure I fully understand the requirement, but if want to use a single expression (i.e. one call to `SelectNodes`) but don't want the leaf nodes, you could try:

```
//*[Member]
```

which is asking for all elements that have a child element called `Member`.

Comment: The thing is, Members could be at any point in a XML document and I don't know exact path to it. I would like to keep it universal and let it to be used recurrently, so the best option is to keep each Member independent from Members element.

Comment: @oleq. Ah - I think I might understand your requirement. You want to use a single expression (i.e. one call to `SelectNodes`) but don't want the leaf nodes?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is an easier way to do this but with using Linq I found it to be easy:

```
var members = XElement.Parse(myXML).Element("Members");
Func<IEnumerable<XElement>, IEnumerable<XElement>> NoNested = (x) => {return x.Select(n => new XElement("Member", new XAttribute("Name", (string)n.Attribute("Name"))));};

var xml = XElement.Parse(myXML);
var selABC = NoNested(xml.XPathSelectElements("./Members/Member"));
var selA = NoNested(xml.XPathSelectElements("./Members/Member[@Name='A']/Member"));
var selC = NoNested(xml.XPathSelectElements("./Members/Member[@Name='C']/Member"));
```

Here is [Dotnet Fiddle Sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oi9kKy)